# React vitest innerHTML toEqual

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm trying to test a Reactnode with react, vitest and the teasting libary.

But the formatting from the innerHTML wil not match. How I can aviod the formatting for testing cases?

```
  - Expected  - 3
  + Received  + 1
  
  - <div>
  -   content
  - </div>
  + <div>content</div>
```

Here my test code

```
    const content: ReactElement = (<div>content</div>);
    makeSUT('title 2', content);

    const contentResult = await screen.findByTestId('modal-content');
    expect(contentResult).toBeInTheDocument();


    expect(contentResult.innerHTML).toEqual(content);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, using `innerHTML` in that manner can be flaky and fail due to something as simple as difference in newlines, which is not how you want to be testing your application(s) and is irrelevant to whether it is working properly.

Instead of comparing the `innerHTML` of two `<div>` elements, to include their semantic tags, I recommend using `findByText` to determine if the text exists in the document.

For example:

```js
    const contentWrapper = screen.getByTestId('custom-element');
    const contentResult = screen.findByText('content');
    
    // If the component with the test id is in the document, it rendered
    expect(contentWrapper).toBeInTheDocument();

    // contentResult will not be find the text if it is not there and this will fail
    expect(contentResult).to.exist;
```

Really though, the assertions above are redundant as "content" won't be in the document if the component didn't render, and `getByText` will throw an error if no text is found (both in the assertion, and because of how `getByText` functions.

Example:

```js
    const contentResult = screen.findByText('content');

    expect(contentResult).to.exist;
```

Why do I recommend using `getByText` over using a test id? [Testing library](https://testing-library.com/) (which you are using and is not specific to Vitest) documentation recommends use of test ids to query elements as being the least preferable/recommended query method.

From the [testing library documentation](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority): "The user cannot see (or hear) these, so this is only recommended for cases where you can't match by role or text or it doesn't make sense (e.g. the text is dynamic).", which is in contrast to their principles of "your test should resemble how users interact with your code (component, page, etc.) as much as possible."

To see a working example of what I have described, I created a [demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-gpebta?file=src/App.test.tsx).